# PHP string cut short

Tags: php, string, special-characters, echo, html-entities

Why does this code

```
$string = "!@#$%^&*(<a@g.com"; 
echo $string;
```

only output:

```
!@#$%^&*(
```

Is this is a PHP bug?

Comment: is it dynamically generated string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because < is a reserved character in in HTML :)

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Read this for more information

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp

You can use the function htmlspecialchars to convert such special chars

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing that:

http://ideone.com/zhycx

Perhaps you've got some weird characters in your file? Make sure you're using a "normal" encoding on your source code, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
echo htmlentities($string);
```

to display the string as it is on a browser. This is because the `<` in the string is interpreted by the browser as start of a HTML tag.

So it's not PHP but the browser that is causing this behavior. If you do the exact same display on a command line, you'll see all the characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing the output in a web browser, then the `<` begins a tag and is usually not displayed but interpreted in the HTML document structure parser. Also, a `$` inside of a double-quoted string is interpolated as the variable name that follows it; try using single quotes where this won't happen.

Try this:

```
$string = '!@#$%^&*(<a@g.com';
echo htmlentities($string);
```